# How can someone run RequestFactory's ValidationTool from ant?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I use:

```
<java failonerror="true" classname="com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.ValidationTool">
   <arg path="${path.to.ouput.jar}" />
   <arg value="com.my.RequestFactory" />
   <classpath>
      <path refid="my_classpath" />
   </classpath>
</java>
```

my_classpath has all requestfactory-client.jar, requestfactory-server.jar, requestfactory-apt.jar + my source & the jar produced from it in the path (that's confirmed with just printing it), but I still get:

[java] error: Unable to find RequestFactory built-in type. Is requestfactory-[client|server].jar on the classpath?

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works only, if I specify `<javac fork="true" ...`

From the official ant documentation on the [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

> If odd things go wrong when you run this task, set fork="true" to use a new JVM.

Without any deep investigation, I would say it's most likely a classloader problem.